# How to calculate materials ability to resist penetration

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, material-science, projectile, stress-strain

I would like to ask you this question which I struggle to answer.

If I have a plate of some material X to which I am shooting at with a tank main gun with ammunition parameters: weight $= 10\text{kg}$, velocity $= 1550 \text{m/s}$, length $= 0.8\text{m}$, tip area $= 1\text{mm}^2$.

Now I calculate the pressure which this round produces at impact like this: $$P = \frac{F}{S} = \frac{10\times\frac{1550^2}{1.6}}{0.000001} = 1.5\times10^{13}.$$

So if I wanted this plate to have no plastic deformation (permanent deformation) after impact then this material must have yield strength of $1.5\times10^{13}$.
Am I right so far?

But if I would like to calculate this in terms of toughness that material X must have instead of yield strength, then I calculate the kinetic energy of this round which is $12 \text{MJ}$. Now how can I calculate over which area is this $12\text{MJ}$ distributed to get the final $\text{J/m}^3$ for required toughness? Since $1 \text{Pa} = 1 \text{J/m}^3$ then can it be said that the required toughness must also be at least $1.5\times10^{13}\text{J/m}^3$ 
Is that right or should all of this be calculated differently?

Thank you very much,

have a nice day.

Comment: I understand that this is a theoretical rather than a practical question, but regardless of the magic material it’s hitting, the tank round would not support that much tip pressure—it would flatten on impact, spreading the force over an area much larger than 1 mm^2.

Comment: Yes I knew that but there is no way of calculating the expansion so it is excluded from this calculation and therefore the result can be thought of as a high end result

Comment: How did you calculate the area of contact? This where you need to call upon the Hertzian contact theory to find the actual stress under a contact.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid permanent damage, you need to guard the surface against [*brineling*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brinelling). This means that there is a limit of contact pressure beyond which subsurface stresses exceed yield and the surface creates an indentation.

Let's say you know the brineling limit $P_{\rm max}$. Next you need to use [Hertzian contact theory](http://www.mech.utah.edu/~me7960/lectures/Topic7-ContactStressesAndDeformations.pdf) to calculate the force needed to reach this level. In the end you will get a pressure-force function of the form $$P  \propto F^{1/3} $$ for a sphere on flat type of contact, as well as a displacement-force function of the form $$ \delta \propto F^{2/3} $$

But what you have is not a static case, but a projectile with certain kinetic energy. At peak deformation, the kinetic energy equals the elastic energy of the contact

$$ \frac{1}{2} m v^2 \propto \int \limits_0^\delta F\,{\rm d}x \propto \tfrac{2}{5} \delta ^ {5/2} $$

or the maximum dispacement being $\delta \propto m^{2/5} v^{4/5}$ and the force $F \propto m^{3/5} v^{6/5}$ .

Finally the contact pressure is $$ P \propto m^{1/5} v^{2/5}$$

So that is how you find how strong a plate is against brinelling.

Comment: I am sory, but what does that mean that P is proportional to m1/5v2/5? May I ask you how to calculate the exact pressure that the projectile exerct upon impact ?

Comment: So may I ask you is the yield strength of 1.5*10^13 Pa correct or must the plate have different strength? Thank you really much for an answer

Comment: Look at slide 7-8 in the attached pdf about Hertzian stress. You see that maximum von Mises stress is about 0.97 of contact pressure. If you know your yield strength then max pressure is 1/0.97 of yield. That is only for spherical contact. You might have other contact conditions.

Comment: and is the yield strength calculation with result of  1.5*10^13 Pa correct? If so then this plate can withstand pressure of 0.97% of 1.5*10^13 right?

Comment: No, your calculation is not correct because it assumes _fixed_ contact area. But the contact area changes with load. In addition, it assumes the pressure if constant throughout the contact, which is not either.

Comment: All right and is it a good aproximation at least? Would be actual result be larger or smaller then this aproximation? And the main point of this my question is, how to make a correct calculation, may I ask you that? Thank you

Comment: @PanMrož - The equation $\frac{1}{2} v^2 = \int_0^\ell a\,{\rm d}x = a\,\ell$ you are using assumes a constant deceleration $a$ over the entire length of the object $\ell$, but you are checking for a condition that no yield exist which is counter to the gross plastic deformation required to absorb the entire projectile.

Comment: well the plate wont plasticaly deform that is the whole point, the projectile would shrink/deform to very small length (basicaly it would be like panckae) I sort of get that my calculation calculates the average pressure that is exerted and THE question is how to calculate the max pressure that occurs. Then we could say that the required strength is that of the max pressure. So please may I ask you, how to calculate that max pressure? Thank you

Comment: As you can see [in this video](https://youtu.be/AkB81u5IM3I) any impact is immensely more complex than imagined and the time of max pressure may not be the time of max displacement (due to the spreading of the contact area).

Comment: I get it but to summarize do you think that it could be said that the strength required is roughly that   1.5*10^13 Pa?? And by roughly I mean the same order of magnitude.

Answer (score 1):

Hi welcome to Physics SE.

I'm not sure I agree with the first part totally : the force exerted on the amunition is $F= \Delta p /\Delta t $. $\Delta p=m v$ and u're assuming $\Delta t= L /  v$ which is a good scaling but not an exact result I think. But why do u put a factor 1/2 ?

Concerning the second reasoning, it is also an approximation, but it looks ok.

EDIT : Actually if we make the approximation that the velocity descreases linearly with respect to the time : $v(l)=v_0 (1- l/L)$. The mean velocity over $L$ is $v=v_0/2$. Then we can write $\Delta t = 2 L /v_0$.

Comment: well I calculate the force F = ma where a = v^2 / 2*d so that is (1550*1550)/(2*0.8) so deacceleration F = 10*1501562.5 = 15015625 N. Is that calculation right for the force that is exerted upon the plate?

Comment: And so is the calculation right that for the plate to sustain no pernament damage it must have yield strength of atl least 1.5*10^13 Pa?

Comment: Yeap but why are u writing the acceleration like that ? That's what I didn't really understand

Comment: I found that somewhere. :) But the important think is that the required strength is 1.5*10^13 Pa right?

Comment: I would be interested to have the reference. I would say it's the right value, but more because of the second reasoning. But I feel like everything here is only going to give you some approximation. So truly one can't say it's 1.5E13 or 2E13 or 1E13, just that it's something around that. But apparently u need the value for some homework or something (??)...

Comment: But yeah I just got it, we assume that the velocity decreases linearly with respect to the time, so with that approximation it gives $1.5E13$ indeed

Comment: Yeah the question is if that aproximation is correct or if the real value is a bit higher due to a fact that this is sort of a average pressure

Comment: In other worlds the question is how to calculate the max force that the projectile project upon impact. Then we can calculate strength of the material based on that max force

Comment: No it is not a homework I just wanna know. And I don´t really need a preceise number just confirmation that it is in the order of magnitede of 10^13 Pa.